# Stability of a dimer on a square grid after $n$ random steps

Tags: probability, markov-chains, random-walk

On a white square grid there are two black cells. Each step consists of each of the cells 'moving' in one of the four directions with equal probability $p_0=1/4$ (a cell can't stay in the same place).

> Let's say we start with a dimer (two cells sharing the same edge). What is the probability that after $n$ steps we again get a dimer?

The general condition for the dimer is:

$$d=|x_1-x_2|+|y_1-y_2|=1$$

With $(x_k,y_k)$ as the integer coordinates of the cells on the grid.

After each step the coordinates become:

$$(x_k,y_k) \to (x_k \pm 1 ,y_k \pm 1)$$

$\pm 1$ means either $+1$ or $-1$ with equal probability, independent for $x$ and $y$. Which also means that the distance always stays odd:

$$\Delta d=\{0,2\}$$

- After $1$ step there are $4^2=16$ possible states. They make $3$ distinct shapes, up to rotation (see the picture):

[image]

Thus, the probability of the dimer staying together after $1$ step is:

$$P_1=\frac{9}{16}$$

- After $2$ steps there are $4^4=256$ possible states. However, it's still possible to track all the states that lead back to a dimer:

$$P_2=\frac{9^2}{16^2}+\frac{1^2}{16^2}+\frac{6}{16} \cdot \frac{3}{16}=\frac{25}{64}$$

It's significantly harder to track all the possibilities for $n=3$, but I'll try (I track all the transformation that ultimately lead to a dimer):

$$P_3=\frac{25}{64} \cdot \frac{9}{16}+\frac{9}{16} \left( \frac{1^2}{16^2}+\frac{6}{16}  \cdot \frac{3}{16}\right)+\frac{6}{16} \left( \frac{7}{16} \cdot \frac{3}{16}+\frac{2}{16}  \cdot \frac{1}{16}\right)+\frac{1}{16} \left( \frac{4}{16} \cdot \frac{3}{16}+\frac{4}{16}  \cdot \frac{1}{16}\right)=\frac{1225}{4096}^*$$

$^*$ I edited the value, since I put an incorrect calculation of the LHS before. Now it's correct.

> Is there a general method to obtain the probability of a dimer after $n$ steps? Or even an explicit expression? Or at least, some approximations for large $n$?

Comment: I suspect what you can do is consider one of them as "stationery" and the other one moves two steps each turn.  This would keep the other on black squares of a checkerboard.  ...which then lets you rotate the whole thing $45$ degrees.  Then you can create the kernel (think it's $1,2,1;2,4,2;1,2,1$, all over $16$, as a grid), and you can convolve that a bunch of times, and then if you start at $(0,0)$, then $(0,0)$, $(0,1)$, $(1,0)$, and $(1,1)$ are the four cells you add up to find the probability.  Might be easier to think at that way.

Comment: An observation about the value of using calculations like this to make conjectures: it's easy to see that $P_1 = 3^2/2^4, P_2 = 10^2/2^8, P_3 = 35^2/2^{12}$. So one can conjecture the result from recognizing the sequence $3, 10, 35$ as ${2n + 1 \choose n}$ for $n = 1, 2, 3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dan Uznanski has already sketched the solution in a comment; I'll work it out in more detail.

Regard one cell as stationary and let the other cell make two steps at a time. Turn the grid by $\frac\pi4$. Then the walk can be decomposed into two independent simple symmetric one-dimensional random walks. We want the probability that these walks end up at $(0,0)$, $(0,2)$, $(2,0)$ or $(2,2)$ after $2n$ steps, starting from $(0,0)$.

The probability that a simple symmetric one-dimensional random walk goes from $0$ to $2k$ in $2n$ steps is $2^{-2n}\binom{2n}{n-k}$. Thus the probability you want is

$$
\left(2^{-2n}\left(\binom{2n}n+\binom{2n}{n-1}\right)\right)^2=2^{-4n}\binom{2n+1}n^2\;.
$$

The first three values are $\frac9{16}$, $\frac{25}{64}$, $\frac{1225}{4096}$. Your calculation for $n=3$ is correctly set up; you just got the wrong end result; the sum you wrote down is in fact $\frac{1225}{4096}$.

Comment: So now the two cells in our dimer are connected by vertices, not by edges? In the rotated grid?

Comment: @YuriyS: No, the rotation is just to make the paths decompose into independent components. Nothing has changed in the content of the problem; the dimers are in adjacent cells that share an edge.

Comment: @ joriki, but then the coordinates don't make sense (where is the stationary cell located?). As I understood, it is located at $(1,1)$ in the new grid. Then the four possible locations for a moving cell make sense. I did not say it changes the content of the problem though, it seems the same to me, just rotated

Comment: @YuriyS: I think I see now how you're thinking about it. I wasn't thinking of a new grid, just a rotated coordinate system for the same grid. If you draw a new grid for the new coordinate system, then yes, in that new grid the dimer consists of two diagonally adjacent cells that share a vertex. Yes, the stationary cell is located at $(1,1)$ and the moving cell is originally at $(0,0)$ in the new coordinates.

Comment: @YuriyS: See also my edit in the answer about your own calculation for $n=3$.

Comment: @ joriki, thank you, I checked and edited it